# regex to match a character only if not followed by another character, then replace just that initial character

Tags: regex

For instance,

```
(/=[^>]/, '═')
```

I'd like to keep that match, but only replace the equals sign with the double-horizontal-line.  As it is, it matches any '=' that is followed by anything that isn't a '>' but then replaces both the '=' and the following character with the replacing character, I want to keep the following character, but replace just the '='.  This is in ruby, if it makes any syntactic difference.

Example input:

```
= render :partial => 'file'
```

First = should be converted, second should be preserved

Comment: Please give example inputs and outputs.  Your existing regex can't demonstrate your goal if it's wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on your regex library (I don't know Ruby), you may be able to use zero-width assertions:

```
/=(?!>)/
```

Note that this regex is slightly different to your regex, but it matches the description you gave in the title better. It will match any `=` that isn't followed by `>`. This includes matching an `=` at the end of the text, which your version won't match.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  (I am using `-` instead of that special character you have):

Inside of irb:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "=x".gsub(/=([^>])/, '-\1')
 => "-x" 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "=>".gsub(/=([^>])/, '-\1')
 => "=>"
```